# REST service authentication : where to store user credentials?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC web application. The application is consuming a REST API, but authentication for REST-full application is quite unclear for me.

As REST is stateless, do I have to implement two different Authentications with two different databases, one for client, and one for the REST service?

Or, do I have to send the login/password each time, to authenticate on the server?

Please give me some advice or tutorial on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can authenticate a Web API using individual user accounts that are stored in a database.
In this case client should obtain access token first. And then include it to each request, that requires authorization, header:

```
Authorization: Bearer boQtj0SCGz2GFGz[...]
```

Good tutorial can be found [**HERE**](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)

Also authentication methods could be extended in Startup.Auth.cs with Cookies or some [external](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services) authentication methods (Google, Facebook etc)

Answer (score 0):

The stateless isn't a main problem in your situation, problem is that browser can only send  GET or POST request in tradition way in tag **form**, so to send PUT or DELETE request you should use Ajax, the easiest way is to use JQuery library and config it to send user credentials in http header(between requests it can be store  in cookies)   in every request and use  basic-authentication if you plan use own auth logic. I recommned you to look  some SPA frameworks like [angularjs](http://angularjs.org/) 
or [emberjs](http://emberjs.com/) 
or [backbonejs](http://backbonejs.org/)
to simplify your life from hardcode JavaScript . Also in future you can easy extend your auth by OAUTH 2.0.